# How to catch internal error message thrown inside a package/library?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, passport.js

How can I catch an internal error message in nodejs/express js that is thrown from a package that I am using (e.g passport)

Answer (score 0):

Hey there it's best to use try and catch blocks in your code in order to see errors thrown from the third party api's

```
try {
// your code here
}catch(error){
 console.log(error)
}
```